# Cannot use freeze_graph.py on my tf meta files

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used the following commands in my TF file to generate .meta files.

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model'+str(i))
```

Then it generates 4 outputs: checkpoint, .index, .meta, .data-00000-of-00001 files

Then i used freeze.graph.py file on the same path as my .meta file is and used the following command and see the error provided below:

```
user1:~/test$ python freeze_graph.py --input_graph graph.pbtxt --input_checkpoint my_test_model1 --output_nodes_names output_my_test_model1 --output_graph /tmp/out
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "freeze_graph.py", line 56, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import saved_model_utils
ImportError: cannot import name saved_model_utils**
```

Comment: save_model_utils.py is also in the same directory

Comment: I removed that error line (commented it) and see:

Comment: raise self.ParseError('Expected identifier or number, got %s.' % result)
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2:1 : Expected identifier or number, got ▒.